# Using dbeaver 'SQL Error [42830]: ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "Clinic"'

Tags: sql, postgresql

Really struggling with the below SQL syntax. I keep getting the error:

> SQL Error [42830]: ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "Clinic"

I've tried using unique and can't seem to work out the issue. Appreciate any help. Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE "Clinic" 
(
    "Clinic ID" Int unique,
    "Location" Varchar,
    "Geolocation" Geometry,
    "Catchment" Geometry,
    "Doctor ID" Int,
    "Patient ID" Int 
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES "patient"("Patient ID"),

    PRIMARY KEY ("Clinic ID")
);

CREATE TABLE "Doctor" 
(
    "Doctor ID" Int unique,
    "Name" Varchar,
    "Date of birth" Date,
    "Specialism" Varchar,
    "Clinic ID" Int,

    PRIMARY KEY ("Doctor ID")
);

CREATE TABLE "Patient" 
(
    "Patient ID" Int unique,
    "Clinic ID" Int,
    "Name" Varchar,
    "Date of birth" Date,
    "Date of death" Date,
    "Gender" Varchar,
    "Address" Varchar,
    "Geolocation of address" Geometry,
    "Disease" Varchar,
    "Start of Disease" Date,
    "End of Disease" Date,
    "Lethal" Boolean,

    PRIMARY KEY ("Patient ID"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_Patient.Patient ID"
        FOREIGN KEY ("Patient ID") REFERENCES "Clinic"("Patient ID")
);

CREATE TABLE "Disease" 
(
    "Severity" Varchar,
    "Name" Varchar,
    "Type of Disease" Varchar,

    PRIMARY KEY ("Name"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_Disease.Name"
        FOREIGN KEY ("Name") REFERENCES "Patient"("Disease")
);

CREATE TABLE "Agency" 
(
    "Clinic ID" Int,
    "Doctor ID" Int,
    "Agency ID" Varchar,

    PRIMARY KEY ("Agency ID"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_Agency.Clinic ID"
        FOREIGN KEY ("Clinic ID") REFERENCES "Clinic"("Clinic ID"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_Agency.Doctor ID"
        FOREIGN KEY ("Doctor ID") REFERENCES "Doctor"("Doctor ID")
);
```

Comment: `REFERENCES "Clinic"("Patient ID")` is referring to a field `"Patient ID"` that is not `UNIQUE`. It makes no sense anyway as you don't want `"Patient ID"` to be `UNIQUE` in `"Clinic"` as it a child record. In fact the relationships as a whole are not making sense. You might want to spend some time figuring out if this is really what you want?

Comment: ok I'll have a look at my relationship structure thanks!